# Cygwin can't compile my program

Tags: cygwin

I have a programm which I want to call gpp to compile a c++ program but I can't do this. When I run the program, I get the message:

> foo.hs: g++: createProcess: permission
>   denied (Permission denied)

What can I do to fix this?

foo.hs is a small haskell script which call g++ it looks like:

```
import System.Cmd
main = do
system "g++ -c test.cpp"
putStrnLn "done"
```

Comment: The compiler is `g++`, not `gpp`. And what is `foo.hs` ?

Comment: foo.hs is a haskell script which call g++

Comment: You might want to add this information to your question and a little more background info

Comment: Stupid question: Does g++ work correctly when you try it manually?

Comment: Perhaps it might be a good idea to show the contents of that script as well. Try to provide as much information you can think of, instead of the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess this happens because 'g++' is a Cygwin symlink yet Haskell isn't a Cygwin program. Try invoking 'g++-3' or 'g++-4' directly.